# UILabel implemente autoheight with center placement and a button to the right using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I want to have a UILabel with a button to it's right centered horizontally like of the picture.

[image: Placement example]

I've implemented an "Align by Horizontal center" for the UILabel and standard space between label and button and it usually works just fine.
The problem appears when UILabel's text is very long and it goes out of bounds and the button is not even visible.

I've tried to set lines count for the UILabel to 0 and set `questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.questionLabel.frame)`what makes the label to grow vertically. But it's width is very small (it's the base width from ui designer) so it looks like a column of text.

So the question is how to make UILabel to:

- to fill all available horizontal space without hiding the button
- autoscale vertically if there is no enough horizontal space to fit text into one horizontal line
- be centered horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's missing the constraint from the `trailing` of the `UIImageView` to the trailing of your container view or margin. I used a `Greater Than or Equal` constraint so if the label has a short length, the image will stay close to the label - using the `horizontal space` constraint from the label to the image.

[image]

With that, your label - that is centered relative to your view, will be centered and will respect your `trailing` constraint of the `UIImageView` to the view using all the horizontal space that is possible to use as follow:

[image]

In the following image it's possible to see that the label reaches the maximum width it can, according to the constraints:

[image]

Comment: It worked! I also had to remove `questionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.questionLabel.frame)` as it was forcing the original frame to stay.

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the width constraint and add a horizontal space constraint from the right side of your label to your image and one from the left side of your label to the left border of your view (set the constant to the minY Value of your Image to get it centred)

[image: Example implementation]